# Choices for dealing with a signal?

Tags: signals, trap

From APUE

> A process  has  three  choices  for  dealing  with  a signal.
>
> 1. Ignore the  signal. This  option  isn’t  recommended  for  signals  that  denote  a hardware exception,  such  as  dividing  by  zero or
>      referencing  memory  outside the address space of the process, as the
>      results are undeﬁned.
> 2. Let the  default  action  occur. For  a  divide-by-zero condition,  the  default  is  to terminate the process.
> 3. Provide a function that is called when the signal occurs (this is called ‘‘catching’’ the signal). By providing  a  function of our own,
>      we’ll know when the signal occurs and we can handle it as we wish.

1. I think there is only two choices -  the last two listed above, and
   both of them can  "ignore the signal" (the first choice listed
   above).

   Is my understanding correct, or are there indeed three
   nonoverlapping choices as in the quote? Why?
2. The book mentions that the default action of some signal is to
   ignore it. Does it mean the action of the signal is SIG_IGN or
   SIG_DFL or an empty function? For example:

   > The **default** action for SIGCHLD is to be **ignored**.  We describe these  options  in  Chapter  10.
   >
   > SIGCONT: The  **default**  action  is  to  continue  a  stopped  process,  but  to  **ignore** the signal  if  the  process  wasn’t 
   >   stopped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course one can write a signal handler that does nothing, and thus effectively ignoring the signal, but the first option is to specifically ignore the signal by using the `SIG_IGN` argument the `signal()` system call.

So in terms of code, assuming the `SIGINT` signal, these are the three options:

- `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);` to ignore
- To not call the `signal()` function, or to call it with `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);` and thus to let the default action occur, i.e. to terminate the process
- `signal(SIGINT, termination_handler);`, where `termination_handler()` is a function that is called the first time the signal occurs.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html

For the specific case of signals were the default action is to ignore the signal, the two first options (`SIG_IGN` and `SIG_DFL`) are identical. Creating an empty handler function probably won't have a visible effect, other than a (small) overhead.

NOTE: The `signal()` is used in this answer for simplicity, but in new code `sigaction()` is recommended for reasons of portability.

Comment: Thanks. In "the first option is to specifically ignore the signal by using the SIG_IGN argument the signal() system call", do you mean that  [signal()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) is a system call, compared to [sigaction()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)?

Comment: Just to clarify, sigaction() is also a system call

Comment: I also see in the book mentioning that the default action of some signal is to ignore it. Does it mean the action of the signal is SIG_IGN or SIG_DFL or an empty function?

Comment: Yes for signals that the default is to ignore, then the options are identical

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the options are identical". Do you mean "SIG_IGN" and "SIG_DFL" are identical for some signal but not for others? If yes, that is confusing. See my update to mypost.

Comment: @Tim: If the default is to ignore, explicitly setting it to SIG_IGN won't change anything. If the default is to take an action (such as terminating the process) obviously ignoring the signal will change the semantics. Could you clarify what is confusing about it?

Comment: (1) See my post for "default is ignoring" question. (2) Also for whether `system()` is a system call, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616899/is-signal-a-system-call-function

Comment: @Tim (1) I already did that both before and after the edit. (2) It is included in the [man page about signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). How does the presence of wrapper function change anything?

Comment: are there indeed three nonoverlapping choices as in the quote?

Comment: @Tim: The quote doesn't say that they are non-overlapping. As you said,  only for signals that the default is to ignore the two first choices do the same thing. For the rest of the signals, the outcome of two first choices is different