# Do "caught" and "delivered" mean the same for a signal?

Tags: linux, signals

Do "caught" and "delivered" mean the same for a signal?

In APUE, a signal is called delivered if it is started to be handled.

[The book uses "caught" in many places.](https://books.google.com/books/about/Advanced_Programming_in_the_UNIX_Environ.html?id=_kpsAQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q=caught&f=false)
I haven't found what it means by a signal being caught, compared to "generated", "sent", "pending" and "delivered".

Thanks.

Comment: Tim, really? After 7 years you multi-post a question? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50626793/1

Comment: I'm just surprised that you're not aware of the U&L -- sorry, Stack Exchange -- [policy against multi-posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and didn't delete the SO (eventually SU) question before posting here.

Comment: If you don’t agree with a site’s policies, take it up on Meta or don’t use the site. That policy has existed for at least the 3 years I’ve been here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal that is delivered may cause a core dump, because there is no handler installed.

If you read that a signal gets caught, this means that a signal handler has been installed and this handler is executed.

Comment: Thanks. "A signal that is delivered may cause a core dump, because there is no handler installed." When there is no handler, will the default handler be invoked? Does the default handler "cause a core dump"?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447030/choices-for-dealing-with-a-signal/447032

Comment: `man 7 signal` should tell you which signals default to core dump.

Comment: On a UNIX system, the information you refer to is available with `man signal.h`..