# How can we set up a signal trap to be SIG_IGN and SIG_DFL in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, signals

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447032/674

> So in terms of code, assuming the `SIGINT` signal, these are the three
>   options:
>
> - `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);` to ignore
> - To not call the `signal()` function, or to call it with `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);` and thus to let the default action occur,
>     i.e. to terminate the process
> - `signal(SIGINT, termination_handler);`, where `termination_handler()` is a function that is called the first time
>     the signal occurs.

In bash, how can I set up the handler of a signal to be `SIG_IGN`?

```
trap "" INT
```

sets an empty command `""` as the signal handler. But does it really set the handler to `SIG_IGN`?

When bash executes an external command, it will reset signal traps to default, and keep ignored signals still ignored. So it is important to know how to set up a signal handler to be `SIG_IGN` in bash, and whether setting a signal handler to the empty command `""` is the same as setting it to `SIG_IGN`.

Similar question for how to set up a signal trap to be `SIG_DFL` in bash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the POSIX documentation of [the special built-in utility `trap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap):

> If action is `-`, the shell shall reset each condition to the default value. If action is null (`""`), the shell shall ignore each specified condition if it arises. Otherwise, the argument action shall be read and executed by the shell when one of the corresponding conditions arises.

This means that your script, after `trap "" INT`, will ignore the `INT` signal, and that you may reset the trap to default with `trap - INT`.

Answer (score 2):

I took this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "" INT
trap - INT
```

And ran:

```
$ strace bash script.sh 2>&1 | grep INT
```

Among the output, I see:

```
read(3, "#!/bin/bash\ntrap \"\" INT\ntrap - I"..., 80) = 35
read(255, "#!/bin/bash\ntrap \"\" INT\ntrap - I"..., 35) = 35
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f24e88f2030}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f24e88f2030}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f24e88f2030}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f24e88f2030}, 8) = 0
```

Given the `sa_handler=SIG_IGN` in the first call to `rt_sigaction()` and the `sa_handler=SIG_DFL` in the second, it looks like `trap "" INT` is causing `bash` to really ignore the signal, and `trap - INT` is causing it to reset to the default handler.