# Prevent SIGINT from reaching mysql subprocess

Tags: perl, mysql, signals, sigint

I have a perl script, which indirectly invokes `mysql` (to execute a long SQL script). I would like to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while that script is running, but somehow the signal still reaches `mysql`, which then says "Ctrl-C -- query killed. Continuing normally." (I believe that's from `mysql`)

I have:

- set the `$SIG{INT}` to 'IGNORE' -- indeed, the Perl script keeps running
- set a process group on the Perl script -- indeed, `ps -e -o uid,pid,ppid,pgid,command` shows that `mysql` is in the same process group as my Perl script
- `mysql` is invoked after both of those happened.

Why would that signal still arrive at the `mysql` process, and how do I prevent that?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/90691; the signal is sent to all processes in the process group.  If `mysql` is in the same process group as the Perl script, the Perl script will ignore it and `mysql` won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore signals (`SIG_IGN`) if you write the code (like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232613/how-to-stop-sigint-being-passed-to-subprocess-in-python)  or use `trap` in shell like in [How can we set up a signal trap to be SIG_IGN and SIG_DFL in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447229/how-can-we-set-up-a-signal-trap-to-be-sig-ign-and-sig-dfl-in-bash), i think in perl this is the `perlipc` library https://metacpan.org/pod/perlipc, IPC is *Inter Process Communication*

> You may also choose to assign the strings 'IGNORE' or 'DEFAULT' as the handler, in which case Perl will try to discard the signal or do the default thing.

source: https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/perlipc.5.asp